# ActiveMQBytesMessage writeBytes not working, message not sent

Tags: queue, jms, activemq-classic

I'm trying to send a message to ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.7.0. However, it doesn't seem to reach its target even though there is no error message or anything indicating what went wrong. Eventually the application halts when it's waiting for an answer that obviously never comes. The queue itself isn't registering any incoming messages per web admin console.

The message gets configured as follows:

```java
var bytesMessage = session.createBytesMessage();

// Message Header
jmsMessage.clearProperties();
MessageMetadata metadata = getSomeMetadata();
bytesMessage.setStringProperty("Property", metadata.getSomeProperty());
// etc.

// Write Message
bytesMessage.clearBody();
bytesMessage.writeBytes(payload);
log.debug("BytesMessage: {}", bytesMessage);
```

`session` is a correctly configured session
The `payload` is a non-empty byte array and the `session` gets built this way:

```java
var factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
factory.setBrokerURL(BROKER_URL);
factory.setUserName(USERNAME);
factory.setPassword(PASSWORD);
factory.setClientIDPrefix(APP_NAME);

var connection = factory.createConnection();
connection.start();
var session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

However, the `bytesMessage` that gets logged looks like this:

```
ActiveMQBytesMessage {
commandId = 0, 
responseRequired = false, 
messageId = ID:My-Laptop-13245-1696261289246-1:1:1:1:1, 
originalDestination = null, 
originalTransactionId = null, 
producerId = null, 
destination = queue://MY.ACTIVEMQ.QUEUE, 
transactionId = null, 
expiration = 0, 
timestamp = 1696261289705, 
arrival = 0, 
brokerInTime = 0, 
brokerOutTime = 0, 
correlationId = null, 
replyTo = null, 
persistent = true, 
type = null, 
priority = 4, 
groupID = null, 
groupSequence = 0, 
targetConsumerId = null, 
compressed = false, 
userID = null, 
content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@34bb4e23, 
marshalledProperties = null, 
dataStructure = null, 
redeliveryCounter = 0, 
size = 0, 
properties = {Property=someProperty, ...}, 
readOnlyProperties = false, 
readOnlyBody = false, 
droppable = false} 
ActiveMQBytesMessage{ bytesOut = null, dataOut = null, dataIn = null }
```

Afterwards, I'm trying to send the message like this:

```java
Queue destination = session.createQueue(MY_QUEUE);
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
producer.send(destination, bytesMessage);
```

But the message never reaches the queue.

So especially `size = 0` and the empty `ActiveMQBytesMessage{ bytesOut = null, dataOut = null, dataIn = null }` stood out to me, even though I don't know if this is the reason why the message wasn't sent. Anything wrong with what I did? I'm using `activemq-core:5.7.0`.

Comment: @JustinBertram I've updated my post with more code. We're using Classic because with Artemis, there's some kind of dependency conflict within the project, at least that's what I've heard from colleagues. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's no error whatsoever on the sender side. The application only halts when it's waiting for an answer that obviously never comes. The queue itself isn't registering any incoming messages per web admin console.

Comment: For the Artemis problem, I only know it has to do with JMS v2 vs. v1.1 and that something crashes (maybe legacy code) when we introduce JMS2.

Comment: ActiveMQ 5.7.0 is ancient and there have been numerous releases since then with all sorts of fixes so first thing is to upgrade to the latest release.

Comment: Possible there is a bug in the older message object that fails if you call clearBody on a newly created message, so don't do that as it isn't needed anyway, also don't call clearProperties on a new message, again, not needed.

Comment: I've upgraded to activemq-all:5.18.2, same problem. I fixed the missing properties by dropping the clearProperties(), the missing payload is still an issue though.

Comment: Did you upgrade the client _and_ the broker or just the client?

Comment: Exactly which metric(s) are you inspecting on the web admin console to confirm that the queue has not received a message?

Comment: If you use a `TextMessage` instead of a `BytesMessage` does the message get sent?

Comment: Yes, I updated the broker and the client. I'm afraid I have to correct myself though, bytesOut and dataOut are set BEFORE sending, but not after - I guess the sent BytesMessage gets cleaned up for some reason? I'll try with a TextMessage next.

Comment: Any update here?

Comment: Sorry, it was a totally trivial error... sender and receiver listened to different queues (one falsely used the JNDI name of the queue) and the messages just weren't collected from the queue.